# Comparing two timestamps fail if one is 5 seconds off

Tags: java, timestamp

I need to compare two timestamps and if one is 5 seconds older than the other the condition fails.

I was using just seconds but after 59 seconds the clock goes to 0 which will cause the condition to fail because 57 < 59 but the next seconds 58 < 0 causes a fail.

I'm now trying

```
Long seconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

but the result is something like 10 numbers which I don't know how to test for a 5 second comaprison

I trying to get something like.

```
if ( timestampA > timesstampB )
  so something foo
```

Comment: try `if((timestampA.getTime() - timesstampB.getTime()) > 5000){...}`

Comment: You can convert ms to seconds by dividing by 1000...

Comment: "Long seconds = System.currentTimeMillis();" is going to return milliseconds, not seconds, hence the long numbers!

Comment: Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] before posting here.  This question could have been answered if you had read the Javadoc for `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if ( (timestampA - timesstampB)  > 5000) {`

Will let you know that more than 5 seconds have elapsed.

Comment: what is `timestampA` here?

Comment: Is it not [Timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#getTime()) object?

Comment: Nope, they are `Long` in the example.

Comment: OP, let me know if you need any additional explanation. I'm happy to help. Milliseconds are a great way to go for comparisons because you don't have to worry about `cultureinfo` until/unless you need to convert back.